# dust.js render dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dust.js

I have the below code in my template which gives the desired output when the page is loaded.

Is there a way to have dust render the page dynamically as i am using sockets to update the data

```
{#storylines}
<li>{text|bl|s} <span class="badge yellow">{@negidx}{.}{/negidx}</span></li>    
{/storylines}
```

Socket IO code:

```
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
       $('#newstoryline').before(blurlines(data));
});
```

I've tried simply adding `<span class="badge yellow">{@negidx}{.}{/negidx}</span>` to end of the data but the output is `{@negidx}{.}{/negidx}` - is there any way to have dust.js render the latest data? or will i have to use some sort of jQuery instead of `{@negidx}{.}{/negidx}`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering your templates client-side, this should be easy. Your code would look something like this:

```
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
  if (data) {
    dust.render('storyline', data, function(err, output) {
      if (output) {
        $('#newstoryline').before(output);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

What's going on here:

The returned data should be JSON. Check that something has been returned.

```
  if (data) {
```

Use `dust` to render the template using the returned data.

```
    dust.render('storyline', data, function(err, output) {
```

Check for `output`:

```
  if (output) {
```

Insert the `output` into your page. This is usually done with innerHTML, but you can use whatever works for you. Remember, the `output` is a string at this point.

```
        $('#newstoryline').before(output);
```

Comment: I'm currently rendering templates server side.

Using the normal ` $('#newstoryline').before(blurlines(data));` it does update the data. however it does not render the `{@negidx}{.}{/negidx}` as a value instead it just returns a string.

May have to look at moving to client side rendering if it cant be done server side. do you know what the advantages/disadvantages of server vs client side rendering are?

Comment: You can use both. Just include dust-core.js on your page to use client-side. An advantage of client-side rendering is that you can cache the templates, so the only thing you need to download on page load is JSON.